# How to get header values in laravel testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, testing, laravel-5.1

This is how i get response in test Case

```
$response = $this->call('POST','/api/auth/login',['username'=>'xx','password'=>'xxx'], [/* cookies */], [/* files */], ['HTTP_ClientSecret' => 'xxxx']);
```

Then we can get response content by like this

`$response->getContents()`

i want to know how to get response header data ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do something like:

```
$response->headers->get('content-type');
```

or whatever you need. Also `dd($response->headers);` might be useful to you if you want to see what is in your response headers.

`$this->call()` returns [Response](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Response.html) which is extending Symfony's [Response](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html) and `headers` is an object `ResponseHeaderBag` which has the [following methods](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ResponseHeaderBag.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to `get` it for the testing, you need to `assert` that it has expected values.

Say, you testing the `throttle middleware`, to be sure that no one can try too manycredit cards with your web store, that is your unit test:

```
    $route = route('payment');

    $iMax = 60;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $iMax; $i++) {

        $response = $this->call('POST', $route, []);
        $response->assertHeader('x-ratelimit-limit', $iMax);
        $response->assertHeader('x-ratelimit-remaining', $iMax - $i);
        $response->assertRedirect();
        $response->assertStatus(302);
        $this->assertSame(iMax, $response->headers->get('x-ratelimit-limit'));
        $this->assertSame(iMax-$i, $response->headers->get('x-ratelimit-remaining'));
    }

    // log down headers if needed
    //\Log::debug($response->headers);

    $response = $this->call('POST', $route, []);
    $response->assertHeader('x-ratelimit-limit', $iMax);
    $response->assertHeader('x-ratelimit-remaining', 0);

    $response->assertStatus(429);
```